# Why do I get error can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' PYTHON

Tags: python

I wrote a simple program to calculate tax for some electrical parts, it goes like this:

```
print "How much does it cost?",    
price = raw_input()    
print "Tax: %s" % (price * 0.25)    
print "Price including tax: %s" % (price * 1.25)    
raw_input ("Press ENTER to exit")
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moms.py", line 3, in <module>
    print "Tax: %s" % (price * 0.25)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string that's returned by `raw_input()` to a `float` first:

```
price = float(raw_input("How much does it cost?")) # no need for extra print
```

Comment: thanks for the anwser to everybody, it work now. thanks for help

Comment: @user1796426 If this has answered your question, it is preferable to click the tick (✔) under the votes to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) rather than posting a comment saying thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This means that `price` is not a number. In fact, it's a string, since that's what `raw_input` returns. You'll want to parse it using `float`, or use `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cannot multiply a string by a float maybe waht you want is

```
price = float(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 1):

The `price` is a string. You need to create a float from the string you have input:

```
>>> price_str = raw_input()
123.234
>>> print type(price)
<type 'str'>
>>> price = float(price_str)
>>> print type(price)
<type 'float'>
>>> print "Tax: %s" % (price * 0.25)   
Tax: 30.8085
>>>
```